# Sentry absolute path error in node js and express

Tags: sentry, react-native-sentry, sentryreact

Sentry error
[image]

getting this error in sentry if i am using sentry.

We've encountered 1 problem un-minifying your applications source code!

captureException but not occouring in sentry.captureMessage. is there any way to remove stack frame to get the relative path?